# Problem with change position of Sidebar

Tags: blocks

I am using the **Droupon** theme of Drupal. I am facing problem while changing the sidebar from right to left. Using CSS I can change it. But I want to know if I can change the position of the sidebar from admin panel without any modification in the CSS.

Thanks
Subha.

Answer (score 0):

- If it is available in theme options at http://example.com/admin/appearance/settings/drupon then you can.
- If Drupon provides both "left sidebar" and "right sidebar" regions, you can move blocks from one region to the other at http://example.com/admin/structure/block
- If it's compatible with Panels or other fast theming system, see it's documentation
- If none above, you need to subtheme to alter CSS or structure.

Comment: In mysite appearance settings I find the 3 column layout(leftsidebar,content,right sidebar) is set as default. But in block setting left sidebar option is not appearing. Is there any chance if it is hidden or not?

Comment: Not really, Drupal does not have concept of options hidden from uid 1 user (aka first administrator). It may be a bug, or maybe this theme is using another name for left sidebar. Either way, read the docs and consider posting in theme's issue queue.

Comment: I tried all the block option.But not getting any success.Get the name of the right sidebar as "Sidebar second". But not get any name for the left sidebar in the block setting.

Comment: wouldn't it be just "Sidebar first"?

Comment: Nothing for the left sidebar.But it is showing default layout is  a 3 column layout.